# Stationary distribution of an ergodic Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stationary-processes, transition-matrix

Let $S_i$ be a Markov chain with transition Matrix $ P $ $ (0 ≤ p ≤ 1) $

\begin{equation*}
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1-2p & 2 p& 0 \\
p & 1-2p & p \\
0 & 2p & 1-2p
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

-For which values of p is $S_i$ ergodic?

-What is the stationary distribution?

I know that a Markov chain is called ergodic if it is possible to go from one state to every state (not necessarily in one move). So for $p \neq 0$ $S_i$ is ergodic.

When I try to find the stationary distribution then i get $(0,0,0)$ which doesn't seems right because summing these values must give us $1$.

Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: A few comments. First $p \le 1/2$ otherwise the transition matrix is ill-defined. Second, does a Markov chain always admit a stationary distribution?

Comment: @Gregory A finite Markov chain always does.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In this link {https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2017/REUPapers/Freedman.pdf} is stated that any distribution will converge to the stationary distribution
over time ( with only mild constraints ).

Comment: Getting only $(0,0,0)$ as a solution indicates that there is something wrong with your algebra, so it would be helpful if you included that in your question so that we can tell you what is wrong. Also, you might want to check those "mild constraints" in this case, because they do not hold for all values of $p$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov if I use the condition that $\pi_{1\ }+\ \pi_2+\pi_3\ =\ 1$ then I get this result: $(\frac{2}{9},\frac{4}{9}, \frac{3}{9}) $.
So, is one of those 'mild constraints' to use the condition mentioned above?

Comment: The condition $\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1$ is a property of the stationary distribution (it is a property of any distribution). The "mild constraints" I take from your comment but I meant the properties that the graph must satisfy in order for convergence to hold. But I do not see how you get this result when $p$ is an arbitrary value, so you should include your work in the question before anyone can tell you what you are doing wrong.